# selenium Automation of MVC application that is uploading, downloading and sharing a files how can i start it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, eclipselink

my application is nothing but a storing files securely and share those to whom i need share i.e to whom use files which i already upload

```
  driver.get("htt://jhfirw");
  driver.findElement(By.id("txtusername")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.id("txtusername")).sendKeys("----------@gmail.com");
  driver.findElement(By.id("txtpassword")).sendKeys("selenium");
  driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
```

but i am not geting how we can simple write a code in TestNG to make reusability of code

Comment: You might want to remove your email address from the code snippet. Also, I'd suggest reading the TestNG documentation regarding invocation.

Answer (score 0):

To start writing a simple code in testNG please check the Link [TestNG](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/index.htm). 
This will help you to understand how to write methods in an efficient and easy way and how they can be re-used. You can easily automate the *uploading,downloading,Sharing* features by Selenium in **TestNG** framework.